# perl command line one liner + delete word after match the line in file

Tags: linux, perl, bash, shell

Please advise how to remove the first word after the line **export PASSORD=**

by perl one liner code ( on linux machines )

For example, I have this line in my file

```
 export PASSORD=HG&@VFQ1
```

the expected results after we run the perl syntax should be without the password

```
 export PASSORD=
```

perl must match exactly the line -->   “export PASSORD=” otherwise password will not be deleted from the file.

examples: The password must not deleted in the following cases:

```
 export PASSORD =HG&@VFQ1
 exportPASSORD=HG&@VFQ1
 export_PASSORD=HG&@VFQ1
 #export_PASSORD=HG&@VFQ1
```

I created the basic perl one liner syntax to delete any word in file but couldn’t successfully add the ability to delete a word only after matching the line --> **export PASSORD=**

```
 perl -i -pe 's/\QANY_STRING//' file
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will delete everything after `export PASSORD=`

```
perl -i -pe 's/^export PASSORD=\K.*//' file
```

For `\K` positive look behind, at Perl v5.10 or higher is required.

For older versions,

```
perl -i -pe 's/(?<=export PASSORD=).*//' file
   -or-
perl -i -pe 's/(export PASSORD=).*/$1/' file
   -or-
perl -i -pe 's/export PASSORD=.*/export PASSORD=/' file
```

Comment: I have perl version - v5.8.8

Comment: your second command says `Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: @Avinash Raj I run the second command without error ( my perl version is 5.8.8

Comment: @Avinash Raj, That message won't be found alone. What's the actual error message? Did you perhaps use that `sh` command in a different shell without compensating?

Comment: please remove the "^" from the syntax of the first perl command ( old versions ) , the export not in the begining og the line

Comment: should be like this - perl -i -pe 's/(?<=export PASSORD=).*//' file

Comment: ok now I have other problem , the perl command also change in the script , for example when I run your perl syntax in my bash script the line of perl command change to ( perl -i -pe 's/(?<=export PASSORD= )  , can you please update the syntax so it will ignore the perl line itself ?

Comment: @maihabunash I'm not sure what is the problem, but it seems that it could be posted under separate question.

Comment: OK I WILL THX and +1 for your exellent solution

Comment: "I have perl version - v5.8.8" - then please do yourself a favour and upgrade to something a little more recent.

Comment: What If I don't want to remove the words after match and want to change only the matched word?   : Got it.  "s/(pattern1)/pattern2/g"

Answer (score 2):

Just use substitution. `^` matches a line beginning.

```
perl -i~ -pe 's/^(export PASSORD=).*/$1/'
```